# python как корректно записать данные типа datetime в MS SQL (тип поля тоже datetime)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, datetime

```
import datetime
import pyodbc    # для работы с БД MS SQL Server (8 версия бд)


now_data = datetime.datetime.now()    # текущ дата
sql_query = f'insert into SVODKA (DATAVZ) values (' + now_data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ')'       # !!! разобрать дату
# !!! convert ???                                    --> !!!

conn = pyodbc.connect(f'DSN=MQIS;UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + password + '')
cursor = conn.cursor()  # соединение

cursor.execute(sql_query)  # <-- our sql
conn.commit()
conn.close()  # close connection
```

[image: пример]

---

> **Значение с датой записывается, но не в корректном формате !**

---

Comment: У вас в коде нет никакого `х`. Имеет смысл приводить то, что стыкуектся с кодом. Например, результат `print(now_data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` Хотя маловероятно, что тут проблема, но тем не менее...

Comment: Используйте параметры. `sql_query = 'insert ... values (?)'` и `cursor.execute(sql_query, now_data)`

Comment: Спасибо все пошло поехало !!! Круто Alexander :))

Answer (score 1):

`SQL` в `string` формате принимает дату в виде `%Y%M%D` без каких либо `-`, то есть нужно использовать:

```
now_data.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: после вашего замечания выдает ошибку теперь такую : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime :/

Comment: буду играться с форматом пока так перебором ) может найдется нужный

Comment: Спасибо за направление ))